# How to add a vector to a table in backend using dbplyr (R)

Tags: sql, r, dbplyr

I created a table from a data source using `tbl()`. I need to add a column including `1:nrow()` to my dataset and tried different methods but I didn't succeed. My code is as below:

```
nrow_df1 <- df1 %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n)

df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(ID = 1:nrow_df1, step = 1)
```

It doesn't add column ID to my dataset and only adds column step.

Using `as.data.frame()`, it works but so slow.

Do you have any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: I tried it already. It needs `as.data.frame()` which makes the process so slow

Comment: Yes, in database. I tried this one as well, but doesn't work

Comment: `df1 <- df1 %>%  mutate(ID = 1:n(), step = 1)` then 
`df1 %>% head()` and gives this error: 
`Error in from:to : NA/NaN argument`

Comment: `In addition: Warning message:
In 1:n() : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: There is something weird there. It doesn't like using a vector for some reason. I proposed an answer that should work for this specific case though.

Comment: This question and the comments below Adam's answer suggest a lot more is wrong than just adding a column. I suggest you verify _connectivity_ to the database and _visibility_ of the table before you go down the road of adding columns. FYI, use `seq_len(nrow_df1)` instead of `1:nrow_df1`, since the latter fails when `nrow_df1` is 0 (try `1:0` to see that it does _not_ return a 0-length vector); while that may seem unlikely when interactive, doing things programmatically/unsupervised opens a new avenue of bugs, and sometimes it's better to start that way up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It is to use `row_number()` but `as.numeric` is also needed to convert the output from integer64 to numeric:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(ID = as.numeric(row_number(a column)), step = 1)
```

Comment: Do you mind including more information on what type of database you are connecting to and how in the question and/or answer? This is a very useful solution to know, but is also a bit specific to what you are connecting to. I think that would be helpful for others. Glad you found it!

Comment: It is Impala and I connect to it using library DBI, `DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Catalyst")`

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you can use `row_number()`.

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)

# simulate a fake database
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)

# add in the row
tbl(con, "mtcars") %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number())
  
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: I use odbc  but `con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Catalyst", ":memory:") ` doesn't work. what is the name of argument relating to `":memory:"` ?

Comment: That was simply for me to create a mock database for a reproducible example. You would connect and create that `con` object however you were doing it before. So you wouldn't use that part.

Comment: I know, but I thought maybe it is needed because I skiped that part and I got this error after `dbWriteTable(...)` : `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"Impala", "character", "tbl_Impala"’`

Comment: and after `tbl(con, "df1") %>% mutate(ID = row_number())"` I got this error `Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1412: HY000: [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : AnalysisException: Could not resolve table reference: 'data12'`

Comment: I think that is now a different problem with connecting to Impala. I don't have practical experience doing that unfortunately :(

Comment: No worries, thank you for your time :)